# How do I take a users input and use it to search an api in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, input, tsx

I am trying to take a users input and then use it to get info from an api in react.

my api url is as follows: `https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${word}`

So I want the user input to correspond to ${word}. I have tried countless attempts with failure. I was able to find a solution with JS and HTML, but using react and type script has me very confused. I am completely new to coding.

heres the code i tried and it works. I just need to translate this into my React.

JS file:

```
async function getDefinition(word) {//to get inputted words 
try {
    const url = `https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${word}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const defined = await response.json();
    return defined;
}


catch (error) {
    console.log("Error:", error.message)
}
}

document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", async (event) => 
{
event.preventDefault();
const word = document.getElementById('string').value;
const defined = await getDefinition(word);
console.log(defined[0].meanings[1].definitions);

 


});



HTML: 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>words</title>
   <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
 awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="module"></script>
</head>

<body>

<header class="header">
<form id="form">
  <label for="string">Search for a definition</label>
  <input id="string" placeholder="Enter word..." type="string">
  <button class="fa fa-search" type="submit"></button>
  </form>
 </header>
```

Comment: Submit the code you used to try to fetch the result in ReactJS. This will help us to fix the code and help you.

Comment: This does not look like react code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need a state to store the word that you want to search in the API.

Secondly, the `handleSubmit` function that will be used to trigger the API.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState();
  const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    fetch(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${text}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setSearchResult(data));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label for="string">Search for a definition</label>
      <input
        id="string"
        placeholder="Enter word..."
        type="string"
        onChange={(event) => setText(event.target.value)}
      ></input>
      <button class="fa fa-search" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I used this code and had to alter a little with type script. Thanks!